# How do I fix this Facebook-plugin error?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I keep getting the following error:

> Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:53
>
> FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

I have tried fixing this by making a new app id and pasting it in the code, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Show your `FB.init()`, `FB.getLoginStatus()` and other code that's relevant to your question. You've just pasted the SDK code which is not useful at all!

Comment: What code? I only have this code and that calls an all.js, but isn't that located at Facebook itself?

Comment: lol, what are you saying ? there must be some other facebook code!

Comment: Ok I will show you all the code I have: